# Import dynamic file with require React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello there I'm importing a dynamic file with require, but my file is outside of `/src` so I check a post that say if I comment two lines in `./node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack-config.js`

I can access to files outside of `/src`, the problem is that if I do this works fine:

```
   <a href={require('../../../../../files/asd.pdf')} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" className="dropdown-item text-center">Show PDF</a>
```

but if i want to be dynamic receiving the path through props i get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../../../../../files/asd.pdf'
```

Where my code is `this` and `this.state.fullPath` is the same of before.

```
  <a href={require(this.state.fullPath)} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" className="dropdown-item text-center">Show PDF</a>
```

I try concatenating a empty string but still not working

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that relates to the module bundler that you are using. In order for it to work, the `require` function has to get a path which the bundler will use to import the module at build time rather than runtime. You will need to use `require` using the full path and not a variable.

You can try something like:

```js
const one = require('./path/to/one.pdf'); 
const two = require('./path/to/two.pdf'); 

const href = variable === 1 ? one : two;
```

```html
<a href={href} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" className="dropdown-item text-center">Show PDF</a>
```

Comment: The problem is that i recive the fullPath by props, so every component has a different path to open thats why i want to be dynamic, the second solution the import one, returns this error `Error: The prop value with an expression type of Import could not be resolved.
  Please file issue to get this fixed immediately.
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)`

Comment: After taking a look again, the dynamic import won't work since it is a downloadable file. Are you not able to pass the the whole `require('../path/to/file.pdf')` as a prop to the component instead of just the path?

Comment: The app got stuck when is compiling if i pass the require by props, the require works only if i have the files inside of `/src` because i did this:

`                                <img src={require(`../../../img/Icon/${this.props.archivo.img}`)} width="128" alt=".." height="126"/>` 

But i need to import outside of /src, because that's what my application is about

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You will need to import the file without a variable path name, I think that it won't work if you don't do that. Since when your app is built with webpack, it will use that path and import the correct file. It won't be able to understand a variable as that is set depending on runtime. You can try import the file at the top of the file before using it without require like: `import file from './path/to/file.pdf'` and use it `<a href={file}>file name</a>` or pass it as prop.